# Can ejs-datepicker in angular 8 is possible in regional language?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am developing angular web application and used ejs-datepicker in application for date selection, Now as a change I want regional language datepicker which as a customer need. So is this possible with ejs-datepicker.

Your answer is valuable to me.

Comment: i think what are you looking is Globalization in the ejs-datepicker, this link can help you with that https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/datepicker/globalization/

Comment: @SuhasMandumale...Thank you for the quick reply. I have also search for same. I need datepicker in india languages like hindi, telugu, marathi etc...Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/datepicker/globalization/

It's not very straightforward. You need to Install two packages, write a bunch of code all around the place and load the language json like this

```
//Load the loadCldr from ej2-base
import { loadCldr } from '@syncfusion/ej2-base';

declare var require: any;

loadCldr(
require('cldr-data/main/de/ca-gregorian.json'),
require('cldr-data/main/de/numbers.json'),
require('cldr-data/main/de/timeZoneNames.json'),
require('cldr-data/supplemental/weekdata.json') // To load the culture based first day of week
 );
```

Comment: Glad it will. Please upvote/accept helpful answers.